# A word meaning "those who are plugged in"?

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm looking for a word that refers to folks who are "plugged in" or "knowledgeable and connected" to some network of people and information.  The "authorities" often connotes law enforcement and therefore doesn't fit well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The Illuminati** is a nice term that describes a community of people with a special/secret knowledge. (Unfortunately, it has been somewhat soiled in recent times by conspiracy theorists and is now most commonly used to label a supposed 'secret society' controlling world governments/media/etc.)

**Enlightened** comes from the same root and describes people endowed with a certain knowledge/understanding. This word often appears in religious context but by no means is it limited to that.

A person with **esoteric** knowledge is someone who knows/understands something which only a select few know/understand. Here, rather than being members of a secret society, the 'select few' are simply those who have studied the topic in question.

**The Intelligentsia** is a term used to refer to intellectuals of a high social class involved in cultural/educational development, creative labour.

If we remove that sense of special/privileged, I suppose any of the following could also work, depending on your specific context:

Nouns: Contributor; Member; Scholar; Academia;

Adjectives: Learned; Erudite;

Most of these latter words tend to relate to *either* knowledge *or* connectedness, rather than both. A dictionary should help you with their specific uses.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Any notes/comments on the downvote? Would appreciate it...

Comment: I thought this was an excellent answer!

Answer (score 4):

Such folks are *in the know* or *in the loop*:

> **in the loop**
>   aware of information known only to a privileged few<sup>NOAD</sup>

An appropriate single word would be the group noun, *the initiated*:

> **the initiated**
>   a small group of people who share obscure knowledge<sup>NOAD</sup>

Answer (score 1):

A contemporary version is **wired**, in the sense of connected.

Answer (score 0):

**cabal** - is a great word with negative, conspiratorial [connotations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cabal), per Wikipedia:

> A **cabal** is a group of people united in
>   some close design together, usually to
>   promote their private views and
>   interests in a church, state, or other
>   community, often by intrigue. Cabals
>   are sometimes secret societies
>   composed of a few designing persons,
>   and at other times are manifestations
>   of emergent behavior in society or
>   governance on the part of a community
>   of persons who have well established
>   public affiliation or kinship.

**cabalist** - an expert who is highly skilled in obscure or difficult, esoteric matters.

Answer (score 0):

These are (mostly) single word terms meaning *those who are plugged in*. Some are nouns, others are adjectives, but I think that is within the scope of the question.

**Cognoscenti**  *n.* To be one of those in the know

**Au courante** *adj.* Well-informed about the latest trends, most current news

**Up-to-date** *adj.* Current

**Ear to the ground**:    This is an idiom. It means to be alert to any changes, immediately.

**On point**:   Also an idiom, implying an alert status

**Insider** *n.* A member of the inner circle, Star Chamber, cabal of those who have a need-to-know

**Hip**  *adj.* The ultimate term for being plugged in: To be hip to something IS to be well-informed.